# session problems when using ajax on codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, session

i am developing for the products website using codeigniter. here i show the product in two view one gird, another one is list view. i was set the view type in session the example code is here

```
$this->session->userdata('proview')=='grid'
```

when hit the first time products menu and select the product view it's working fine. but my problem is the product doesn't loading if select product categorizes wise. i am using jquery-ajax for the product list-view and grid-view ,  the current page products data was assigned to session on ajax. when first time it is working fine but when we go to product categories wise the session was not set. it gave empty array. i did not figure it why it's gave empty array on session

the ajax code is here

```
$('.proview').click(function(){
        var view = $(this).attr('id');          
        $.post('<?php echo base_url()?>productajax',{typ:'proview',view:view},function(data){                                               
             //$(".prolist").replaceWith(data);
             alert(data);
        });
        return false;
    })
```

my session details on config.php

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

please give a good result for this. thanks advance

Comment: Are you using `database session` in your project `$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE` show your config.php

Comment: i am using `database session` and my ` $config['sess_use_database']  = TRUE `